# How to set Cassandra as my Distributed Storage(File System) for my Spark Cluster

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to big data and Spark(pyspark).
Recently I just setup a spark cluster and wanted to use Cassandra File System (CFS) on my spark cluster to help upload files.

Can any one tell me how to set it up and briefly introduce how to use CFS system? (like how to upload files / from where)

BTW I don't even know how to use HDFS(I downloaded pre-built spark-bin-hadoop but I can't find hadoop in my system tho.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CFS only exists in DataStax Enterprise and isn't appropriate for most Distributed File applications. It's primary focused as a substitute for HDFS for map/reduce jobs and small temporary but distributed files.

To use it you just use the CFS:// uri and make sure you are using `dse spark-submit` from your application.

Comment: thank you for your clarification. I am trying to figure it out how to use the distributed file system on my spark cluster. Guess I am asking some stupid questions but appreciate your help.                                             Q1: to access CFS:// do I need to install Cassandra first?                         Q2: If I want to use HDFS do I need to install Hadoop again? (because I downloaded "spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz" but after installation when I type "hadoop" in command it says "hadoop: command not found")

Comment: And how can I check the uri after CFS://

Comment: CFS is *only* part of DataStax Enterprise. So to use it you need to install Datastax Enterprise. Then when you start cassandra in analytics mode you can access it via `dse hadoop`. Hadoop and HDFS must be installed seperately as well, they are not part of Spark. But Spark is only linked against one version of hadoop.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out.